# Trying to fix this to top right of screen

Tags: css, position, css-position

I'm trying to fix this top right, meaning that it stays top right when scrolling, maximizing, and minimizing window. Something like position:absolute; top:0; right:0; .....I can't get it to work. Can you help with syntax?

```
<div align="center" class="socialbtns">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://…..” target="_blank" class="fa fa-lg fa-linkedin"></a>
</li>
<li><a href="https://......target="_blank" class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook"></a>
</li>
<li><a href="http://…..” target="_blank" class="fa fa-lg fa-twitter"></a></li>
<li><a href="https://….” target="_blank" class="fa fa-lg fa-google-plus"></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS is as follows

```
@import url('http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');


a, a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.socialbtns, .socialbtns ul, .socialbtns li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

.socialbtns li {
    list-style: none outside none;
    display: inline-block;
}

.socialbtns .fa {
    width: 40px;
    height: 28px;
    color: #576267;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding-top: 12px;
    border-radius: 22px;
    -moz-border-radius: 22px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 22px;
    -o-border-radius: 22px;
}

.socialbtns .fa:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #576267;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}



</style>
```

Comment: Post your CSS. We need a [mcve]. Also, watch your quotes. Ex `”`

Comment: @j08691 edits made.

Answer (score 5):

Your anchor tags weren't well put together and using the CSS position:absolute with right and top set to 0 to the class .socialbtns. 
Run snippet below to see it work

```css
.socialbtns {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            margin-right: 15px;
        }

        li {
            list-style: none;
            display: inline;
            margin: 5px;
        }
        a {text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="socialbtns">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://….." target="_blank" class="fa fa-lg fa-linkedin"></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://..." target="_blank" class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook"></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://…" target="_blank" class="fa fa-lg fa-twitter"></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://…." target="_blank" class="fa fa-lg fa-google-plus"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```